# How to fix "pyuic5: command not found" in terminal

Tags: python, pyqt

So I am trying to convert a .ui file to a .py file in PyCharm. Whenever I type in the pyuic5 command into the terminal, it returns with "bash: pyuic5: command not found".

I have tried to cd to my project folder, but am still having the same problem. I have already installed the PyQt5 library in PyCharm, so that shouldn't be the problem.

Any suggestions or ideas would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed **pyqt5-tools** module by pip command?
If you have installed this package, you should find **pyuic5.exe** in your Python36/Scripts folder(for Windows OS).

So please check it first.

Answer (score 0):

i fixed that problem after these steps:

1. open your python directory where is python scripts located — C:\Users\ *your user name* \AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\Scripts **OR** C:\Users*your user name*\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts (you may have another version, so just find your)
2. then open **Scripts** folder, and then (if you can't find **pyuic5.exe**, just pip it in cmd in the same folder — **pip install pyqt5** and **pip install pyqt5-tools**) copy that directory
3. then open your folder where do you need use pyuic5, and open cmd in that directory
4. and then in cmd write that directory, and put after ...\Python310\Scripts\ ← **pyuic5**.

—4.5. and its all, just write after that at the same row **-x qtpython.ui -o qtpython.py**

Comment: P.S. 3rd — that directory, which you copied